# Why is this causing a EXC_BAD_ACCESS error in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

When I write this: `hiddenBarBackButton(true)` instead of this: `.hiddenBarBackButton(true)` - *notice dot in the front of the modifier* - I get an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code= 2, ...)` exception. These exceptions normally appear when a function call is causing an infinite recursion, or if there is a pointer trying to access a part of the memory that has already been deallocated (aka dangling pointers).

**But why?**

I don't know how this function is causing the exception when it's not attach to a view. My best guess is that the function is trying to call the view that it's supposed to be attached with, but since this view is non-existent, then... it calls to nothing(?).

Comment: Just a guess but the one **without** the period is likely trying to call on the "parent" view that has been redrawn by SwiftUI and the one **with** the period is the one that is in-sync with the `View`. Just a guess I havent done any testing or research

Comment: You're probably right